# Search CLI tool missing in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to install Sphinx search, I have installed the sphinx in the following steps

downloaded the sphinx from sphinxsearch.com/downloads and extract the tar.gz file.

```
  tar -xzvf sphinx-2.2.6-release.tar.gz
  cd sphinx-2.2.6-release
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
 make
 make install (from the root)
```

when I check the /usr/local/sphinx/bin didn't find **search CLI tool**. can anyone let me know what I am missing while installing Sphinx Search? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The tool has been (intentionally) removed. Its been depreciated for a long time.